# How to import a .pfx certificate in AWS Certificate Manager?

Tags: certificate, pfx, aws-certificate-manager, aws-ssm

How to store a password protected .pfx file in AWS Certificate Manager? By 'password protected', I mean I have a big string (binary of the pfx certificate) which I can save in a file with the extension .pfx. I will be able to install that .pfx certificate in my local machine only if I provide the password.

What will be the

1. certificate body
2. certificate private key and
3. certificate chain?

Is AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) the only place to store this .pfx certificate? Can I store the original pfx string in AWS Systems Manager Params Store?

Comment: In AWS Security Blog I found the answer on your first question https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-import-pfx-formatted-certificates-into-aws-certificate-manager-using-openssl/

Comment: AWS Systems Manager Params Store can’t contain binary files like PFX https://mannix.net/2018/10/19/storing-ssl-certificates-in-the-aws-parameter-store/